# Bug in NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle?

Tags: swift, cocoa

When I use NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle for larger numbers (not numbers that overflow the type) it seems to break down somewhere in the mid-quadrillions.

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle
print(formatter.stringFromNumber(50000000000000000))
```

Output: eighteen quadrillion fourteen trillion three hundred ninety-eight billion five hundred nine million four hundred eighty-one thousand nine hundred eighty-four

What's going on here?  A bug?  Or am I bumping into some limit I'm unaware of?  Int doesn't overflow until 2^63, being 64 bit signed ints... but the number formatter has some limit at 2^54?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a solution but I have a guess:

NSNumberFormatter uses a Double to store the value (53 bits), so your value is too big.

I suppose it makes the formatter generate an erroneous spelling instead of failing with a real error message: so I'd say *yes*, it's a bug with NSNumberFormatterStyle.SpellOutStyle, it should not spit out a dummy value when failing.

Comment: NSNumber is *not* built on double. It is a class cluster and can hold 64-bit integers without precision problems (`NSNumber(longLong:)`). It also has the NSDecimalNumber subclass which represents decimal numbers with up to 38 decimal digits. – It may of course be that NSNumberFormatter uses `double` internally.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks Martin. I've changed the wording of my answer (removed the "NSNumber is built on ..." part). If you think it's still wrong or too vague I'll delete it.

Comment: Btw, the output, 18,014,398,509,481,984 is hexadecimal `40 00 00 00 00 00 00`, which is a 55-bit number. This *could* be related to the size of the mantissa in a binary double (which is a bit smaller). – But here is a funny one: If you change the localization to "de" for German, the output is `"fünfzig Billiarden null"`. The "null" makes no sense, but "fünfzig Billiarden" is a correct result :) – In any case, it is a bug, and without seeing the source code we can only guess where that bug comes from.