# Why can't `NumberFormatter` display maximum `Int` value?

Tags: swift, cocoa, int, nsnumberformatter

This code prints "eighteen quadrillion fourteen trillion three hundred ninety-eight billion five hundred nine million four hundred eighty-one thousand nine hundred eighty-four", but the numeric value of `Int.max` is `9223372036854775807`.

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
print(formatter.string(from: Int.max))
```

Why?

Comment: NSNumberFormatter uses a Double to store the value (53 bits), so your value is too big. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205450/bug-in-nsnumberformatterstyle-spelloutstyle